# How to use instafeed.js to grab videos instead of only photos

Tags: javascript, instagram-api, instafeedjs

I'm currently trying to grab videos only through a user's Instagram's account, however; I'm having some trouble and I'm currently using Instafeed.js to pull the data from instgram. How can I only pull videos? Would I need to use video.js and make my own video player?

Here's my code that ONLY pulls thumbnails from the videos.

```js
 let userFeed = new Instafeed({
     get: 'user',
     userId: 'USER_ID',
     limit: 12,
     resolution: 'standard_resolution',
     clientId: 'CLIENT_ID',
     accessToken: 'ACCESS_TOKEN',
     sortBy: 'most-recent',
     template: '<div class="tile"><div class="text">{{model.user.full_name}}</div><img class="item" src="{{image}}"></div>',
     filter: function (image) {
         return image.type === 'video';
     }
 });
 userFeed.run();
```

Thanks to all who spend time helping me out!

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your filter method as follows and remove template property:

```
filter: function (image) {
    if (image.type === 'video') {
        image.template = '<video width="100%" controls loop><source src="' + image.videos.standard_resolution.url + '" type="video/mp4"/></video>';
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this works pretty good. However, it just makes it a clickable thumbnail that redirects you to the Instragram video of URL. Thanks tho! I might end up just embedding the videos instead of going through their very poor documented API. With all the recent changes they've made.

Comment: Not working for me. It is not even going to the filter function :(

Comment: ```filter: function(image) {
        if(image.type === "video") {
          image.template = `<div class="aspect-w-1 aspect-h-1"><video class="rounded-2xl" src="" controls></div>`
          return true;
        }
        else {
          image.template = `<a href="${image.link}" target="_blank"><img loading="lazy" class="w-full h-full rounded-2xl" src="${image.image}" alt=""></a>`
          return true;
        }
      }```

Comment: @za_ali33 Can you share a jsfiddle? Do you see any console errors?